# drop rows using pandas groupby and filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I'm trying to drop rows from a df where certain conditions are met. Using below, I'm grouping values using column `C`. For each unique group, I want to drop ALL rows where `A` is less than `1` AND `B` is greater than `100`. This has to occur on the same row though. If I use `.any()` or `.all()`, it doesn't return what I want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1], 
    'B' : [101, 2, 3, 1, 5, 101, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    'C' : ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f',], 
    })

df.groupby(['C']).filter(lambda g: g['A'].lt(1) & g['B'].gt(100))
```

initial df:

```
   A    B  C
0  1  101  d # A is not lt 1 so keep all d's
1  0    2  d
2  1    3  d
3  0    1  d
4  1    5  e
5  0  101  e # A is lt 1 and B is gt 100 so drop all e's
6  0    2  e
7  1    3  f
8  0    4  f
9  1    5  f
```

intended out:

```
   A    B  C
0  1  101  d
1  0    2  d
2  1    3  d
3  0    1  d
7  1    3  f
8  0    4  f
9  1    5  f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better performnce get all `C` values match condition and then filter original column `C` by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask:

```
df1 = df[~df['C'].isin(df.loc[df['A'].lt(1) & df['B'].gt(100), 'C'])]
```

Another idea is use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if match at least one value:

```
df1 = df[~(df['A'].lt(1) & df['B'].gt(100)).groupby(df['C']).transform('any')]
```

Your solution is possible with `any` and `not` for scalars, if large DataFrame it should be slow:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['C']).filter(lambda g:not ( g['A'].lt(1) & g['B'].gt(100)).any())

df1 = df.groupby(['C']).filter(lambda g: (g['A'].ge(1) | g['B'].le(100)).all())

print (df1)
   A    B  C
0  1  101  d
1  0    2  d
2  1    3  d
3  0    1  d
7  1    3  f
8  0    4  f
9  1    5  f
```